# MATLAB 'text' function not working with 'sprintf' argument

Tags: matlab, printf

Trying to print the following range of labels in a figure:

`aux = {'ca155.mat','ca154.mat','ca159.mat','ca146.mat','ca148.mat','ca004.mat'};`

But I need it upper case and without the extension, so I use

`text(0,0,upper(sprintf([aux{i},'\b\b\b\b'])));`

In the command window I get the correct output such as for `i=1`, i.e. `CA155`. However the text function on a figure doesn't work and produces:

`CA155.MAT[][][][]`

Except instead of brackets there are closed rectangles (I couldn't copy the character).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Instead of producing a character that deletes the previous character **in a command window**, why not just delete the characters from the array? `aux{1}(1:end-4)` removes the last 4 characters from a string.

Answer (score 1):

When processing your text, you did not delete the extension, you inserted backspaces. Here some insights for demonstration:

```
>> x=upper(sprintf([aux{i},'\b\b\b\b']))

x =

    'CA155'

>> size(x)

ans =

     1    13

>> x(1:9)

ans =

    'CA155.MAT'

>> x(1:10)

ans =

    'CA155.MA'
```

The first 9 characters are still there but the following backspaces delete them when working in a command window. Looks like `text` does not support it, and backspaces are definitely not the way to go.

Use `fileparts` instead:

```
>> [filepath,name,ext]=fileparts(aux{i})

filepath =

  0×0 empty char array


name =

    'ca155'


ext =

    '.mat'
```